# syntax for array of pointers in C++

Tags: c++

So, I see that the practice for dynamic allocating of an array of pointers looks like this:

`int **array = new int *[10];`

And indeed, using syntax:

`int *array[] = new int *[10];`

results in error:

```
/Users/Malachi/Projects/playground/playground.gcc/src/pgccc-5/main.cpp:8: error: definition of variable with array type needs an explicit size or an initializer
    const char* test_array[];
                ^
```

I'm always more comfortable using pure pointer syntax anyway.  However, what bothers me is lines like this:

`int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

are valid.  I'm accustom to empty array brackets [] more or less aliasing out to a pointer type.  It seems to me `char *argv[]` is subject to almost exactly the same constraints as my `int *array[]`, so why is the syntax permitted in one scenario but not the other?

EDIT: It appears the simpler case of `int array[] = new int[10]` exhibits the same behavior

Comment: *"so why is the syntax permitted in one scenario but not the other?"* Because that is what the C designers decided in the 1970's. Not the best idea.

Comment: `new T[]` returns a `T *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one:

```
int *array[] = new int *[10];
```

is not a valid syntax. The reason the left side has a type of *an array of pointers to int*, and the right side has a type of *a pointer to a pointer to int*. So the assignment is not legal due to the different types of left and right sides.

On the other hand, *arrays decay into pointers*. It means, that when you declare a function in the form of:

```
void foo(int* arr[])
```

the compiler sees it as:

```
void foo(int** arr)
```

The rule above applies only for functions, but not for assignments like in the first example.

Comment: So, if the designers of this paradigm chose to make int* arr[] everywhere represent a "sparse" array (aka pointer to a pointer to int) then we'd have a conundrum what syntax to use to declare an *array of pointers to int* on the stack?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm accustom to empty array brackets [] more or less aliasing out to a pointer type.

That's valid only in the declaration of a function argument.

```
void foo(int a[]);
```

is the same as:

```
void foo(int* a);
```

However, when declaring or defining variables, they are not the same.

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3}; // Valid. Array of 3 ints
```

is not the same as

```
int* a = {1, 2, 3}; // Invalid syntax.
```

**Exception**

You can use a string literal to intialize a `char` array or `char const*`.

```
char s1[] = "string 1";
char const* s2 = "string 2";
```

However, you can't use (not in C++ anyway):

```
char* s2 = "string 2";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because function parameter declaration is something different than variable declaration.

An array can decay into a pointer for the first dimension.

You can explicitly express that function expects an array rather than a pointer through the declaration using `[]` notation in e.g `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. They type doesn't matter:

```
void f(int* i[]) {}
```

is legal as well. This says "I want an array of pointers to ints". This is more expressive than:

```
void f(int** i) {}
```